# Get array value form string pattern in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I assume array is

```
Array
(
            [0] => john
            [1] => robinson
            [2] => 27-08-1980
            [3] => football
            [4] => pizza

)
```

And I want to get value from array by use string pattern 
example string pattern (It's can use html code too) :

```
string = "{0} {1} birthday {2} <br /> Hobbie : {3}  <br /> favorite : {4}"
```

Result is

```
john robinson birthday 27-08-1980
Hobbie : football 
favorite : pizza
```

How to solve

Comment: Have you tried to solve it yourself? :)

Comment: Assign this array to some variable then use it

Comment: A nice little [preg_replace_callback()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`vsprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php), but you have to change your template placeholders to %s.

```
$data = array(...); // your array
$template = '%s %s birthday %s <br /> Hobbie : %s  <br /> favorite : %s';
$result = vsprintf($template, $data);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [preg_replace_callback()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

```
$data = [
    0 => 'john',
    1 => 'robinson',
    2 => '27-08-1980',
    3 => 'football',
    4 => 'pizza',
];

$template = "{0} {1} birthday {2} <br /> Hobbie : {3}  <br /> favorite : {4}";

$string = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\{(\d+)\}/',
    function ($matches) use ($data) {
        return $data[$matches[1]];
    },
    $template
);

echo $string;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ESCmH)

Answer (score 0):

A `preg_replace_callback` is going to help you:

```
<?php
$array = array('john', 'robinson', '27-09-1980', 'football', 'pizza');
$string = "{0} {1} birthday {2} <br /> Hobbie : {3}  <br /> favorite : {4}";
$pattern = "/\{[0-9]\}/";

$newString = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) use ($array) {
    return $array[substr($matches[0],1,1)]; 
}, $string);

echo $newString;
```

Above returns:
john robinson birthday 27-09-1980

Hobbie : football

favorite : pizza

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array('john','robinson','27-08-1980', 'football','pizza');
$str = "{$arr[0]} {$arr[1]} birthday {$arr[2]} <br /> Hobbie : {$arr[3]}  <br /> favorite : {$arr[4]}";
echo $str;
```

why don't you try this